# Using Python and Opencv to deskew leaning digits

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am looking to OCR some digital numbers in a couple of different formats. I have a function which levels text on the horizontal plane to enable me to create bounding boxes in Opencv which works for one of my digit images.  However, the second digit style is slightly leaning (italicised), which sometimes works, but I have found the decimal point mostly gets lost as it gets incorporated into one of the digits bounding rectangles.

Is there a way to align the digits based on the vertical lines of the actual digit?

Below is my working function for the horizontal plane:

```
def deskew(img):
    img_edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 100, apertureSize=3)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 100, minLineLength=20, maxLineGap=50)

    angles = []
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
        angles.append(angle)

    med_angle = np.median(angles)
    rotated_img = ndimage.rotate(img, med_angle, cval=255)

    cv2.imshow("rotated image", rotated_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return rotated_img
```

Below is the type of image/digit format I am trying to deskew and OCR, I have found through some manual entries that an angle of around 5 degrees seems to work with accurately drawing separate bounding rectangles to capture the digits and decimal points.

[image]

Below is the manually adjusted angle, showing all digits and decimal point captured, which can be OCR'd

[image]

Comment: Compute the shearing by comparing vertical and horizontal angles and then use `cv2.warpAffine()` method. Or, instead of hough transform, compute convex hull of binarized image (`cv2.findContours()`, then `cv2.convexHull()`), and derive a sheared rectangle from it. Again use `cv2.warpAffine()`, after `cv2.getAffineTransform()`. Might be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I ended up doing a much more simpler (crude) alternative.  As the slant is constant for this type of 'text' at around 5 degrees, I simply deskew on the horizontal plane and then set the angle at 5 degrees and the run the OCR.